# Arbitrarily number of filters on dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a number of filters that i need to apply to a data frame in Spark, but it is first at runtime i know which filters to user. Currently i am adding them in individual `filter` functions, but that fails if one of the filtes is not defined

```
myDataFrame
    .filter(_filter1)
    .filter(_filter2)
    .filter(_filter3)...
```

I can't really find out how to dynamically at runtime exclude fx `_filter2` if that is not needed?

Should i do it by creating one big filter:

```
var filter = _filter1
if (_filter2 != null)
    filter = filter.and(_filter2)
...
```

Or is there a good pattern for this in Spark that i haven't found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to default all `filters` to `lit(true)`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF("x")

val filter_1 = lit(true)
val filter_2 = col("x") > 1
val filter_3 = lit(true)

val filtered = df.filter(filter_1).filter(filter_2).filter(filter_3)
```

This will keep `null` out of your code and trivially true predicates will be pruned from the execution plan:

```
filtered.explain
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [value#1 AS x#3]
+- *Filter (value#1 > 1)
   +- LocalTableScan [value#1]
```

You can of course make it even simpler and a sequence of predicates:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

val preds: Seq[Column] = Seq(lit(true), col("x") > 1, lit(true))
df.where(preds.foldLeft(lit(true))(_ and _))
```

and, if implemented right, skip placeholders completely.

Answer (score 1):

At first I would get rid of null filters:

```
val filters:List[A => Boolean] = nullableFilters.filter(_!=null)
```

Then define function to chain filters:

```
def chainFilters[A](filters:List[A => Boolean])(v:A) = filters.forall(f => f(v))
```

Now you can simply apply filters to your df:

```
df.filter(chainFilters(nullableFilters.filter(_!=null))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
var df = // load
if (_filter2 != null) {
    df = df.filter(_filter2)
}
etc
```

Alternatively, create a list of filters:

```
var df = // load
val filters = Seq (filter1, filter2, filter3, ...)
filters.filter(_ != null).foreach (x => df = df.filter(x))
```

// Sorry if there is some mistake in code, it's more an idea - currently I can't test code